# Calculation in DataGridView column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in which I want to sum up values from two different columns into a third column.

**Example DataGridView:**

```
A   B   Total
1   2    3
25  35   60
5   -5   0
```

I want to add (A+B) in total, just after entering values in `A & B column` or leaving current row. And also want to set Total Column as `ReadOnly`.

Comment: Are you binding this to a datatable?

Comment: No I'm not binding this to any database or table, vales are entered by user.

Comment: Have you tried dataGridView.Columns["Total"].ReadOnly = true; to make column read only?

Comment: Ok, if you did bind it to a datatable I would have suggested using a datacolumn with an expression property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that on CellValidatedEvent and you can apply the same method to RowValidated:

```
 private void dataGridView_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
                if (e.RowIndex > -1) {
                    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                    string valueA = row.Cells[columnA.Index].Value.ToString();
                    string valueB = row.Cells[columnB.Index].Value.ToString();
                    int result;
                    if (Int32.TryParse(valueA, out result)
                        && Int32.TryParse(valueB, out result)) {
                        row.Cells[columnTotal.Index].Value = valueA + valueB;
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can set column to ReadOnly in the designer, or like this:

```
dataGridView.Columns["Total"].ReadOnly = true
```

Answer (score 6):

You could easily do this

But you should have a dataset or localdatabase connection like SQL
I will assume that you got it and name it 
Totaldataset.

Easily done I know it's too late answer but maybe it help some new readers.

```
Datacolumn column = new Datacolumn (); 
column.Columnname = "Total"; 
Totaldataset.Tables[0].Columns.["Total"].Expression = "a+b";
```

Comment: Datacolumn column = new datacolumn ();
Column. Columnname = "Total";
Totldataset.tables[0].coulmns.["Total"].Expression = "a+b";

Comment: Thank you slfan for the help :)

Comment: Thank you slfan for the help ... :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a working example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataGridView _calcDataGridView;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _calcDataGridView = new DataGridView();
        this.Controls.Add(_calcDataGridView);
        _calcDataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        _calcDataGridView.Name = "CalcDataGridView";
        _calcDataGridView.CellEndEdit += Calculate;

        var aColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        aColumn.Name = "AColumn";
        aColumn.HeaderText = "A";
        _calcDataGridView.Columns.Add(aColumn);

        var bColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        bColumn.Name = "BColumn";
        bColumn.HeaderText = "B";
        _calcDataGridView.Columns.Add(bColumn);

        var totalColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        totalColumn.Name = "TotalColumn";
        totalColumn.HeaderText = "Total";
        totalColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        _calcDataGridView.Columns.Add(totalColumn);
    }

    private void Calculate(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        object a = _calcDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["AColumn"].Value;
        object b = _calcDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["BColumn"].Value;
        double aNumber = 0;
        double bNumber = 0;
        if (a != null)
            aNumber = Double.Parse(a.ToString());
        if (b != null)
            bNumber = Double.Parse(b.ToString());
        _calcDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["TotalColumn"].Value = aNumber + bNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If U r using data binding using `Eval`
than U can just create a method there and on that method just sum those two values.

Like

For Column A

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <%# Eval("A")%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

for column B

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Eval("B")%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

For Total

```
 <ItemTemplate>
<%# GetTotal(Eval("A"),Eval("B")) %>

 </ItemTemplate>
```

For total method

```
private string GetTotal(object A,object B)
{
return (A+B).ToString();
}
```

hope this will help you.