# Using 2 different databasecolumn in to single datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I need to display a column called `Full Name` in a `DataGridView`, but the `DataSource (datatable)` does not have a `FullName` column. It only has `FirstName` and `LastName` columns. I'm setting up my `DataGridView` like this:

```
Dim column As DataGridViewColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
column.DataPropertyName = "?" //Need FirstName + " " + LastName
column.Name = "FullName"
dgv.Columns.Add(column)
```

How can I set the `DataPropertyName` to use data from both the `FirstName` and `LastName` columns in the datatable.?

Thanks.

Comment: Steve's answer is very nice - since you already have a datatable that is almost certainly the way to go. For completeness though, it is worth noting that you can have calculated columns in the grid itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097370/calculation-in-datagridview-column

Answer (score 4):

Using another approach.  Add a calculated column to your datatable.

```
Dim dc as DataColumn = dt.Columns.Add("FullName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
dc.Expression = "FirstName + ' ' + LastName"
```

where dt is the datatable that you set as DataSource of your DataGridView.

The rules for the *expression syntax* used in calculated columns could be found at this **[link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx).**
The very same rules apply also to another very useful method: the **[DataTable.Select(filterExpression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx)** method

Comment: Didn't know you could do this. Pretty neat.

Comment: @Yatrix and that's only a small part of syntax available. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's how `DataPropertyName` works. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx

Do this on the database side of things instead. In your select (SQL Server syntax here), do a `FirstName + " " + LastName as FullName` and you'll get a FullName column back instead of the two columns.

If you don't have access to the SQL side, you can manipulate the `DataTable` and create your own `FullName` column in code. I'd imagine some LINQ and/or looping should do the trick.