# how to get auto fill column in dgv by result of summation two columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have dgv  have 3 columns Quantity - Price & Total Price 
i wanna to get Total price automatic when fill other two columns
what is the dgv event to do that  ?

Comment: See previous question, [calculation-in-datagridview-column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097370/calculation-in-datagridview-column)

Answer (score 0):

Following would be the easy approach,

Create a class with 3 properties,

```
public class Sale
{
   public int Quantity { get; set; }

   public int Price { get; set; }

   private int total;

   public int Total
   {
      get
      {
        return this.Quantity * this.Price;
      }
   }
}
```

Now go to DGV column edit view and set each gridview column's `DataPropertyName` to relevant property name of the Sale class. Then populate the `List<Sale>` collection and set it as the datasource of the grid view.

```
List<Sale> salesDetails = new List<Client>;
dataGridView1.DataSource = salesDetails;
```