# Calculation on Datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, datagridview

This is some data on my datagridview and a data is just like this

```
column a | column b
1             0
2          is = 2-1
3          is = 3-2
4          is = 4-3
```

So,I want to know how to calculate in column a and show the answer in column b.

Comment: you need calculated value in 3rd column ?

Comment: @Krishna, OP mentioned that column b should contain calculated value. Op want how to do that in datagridview

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ how do you calculate with only one value you need 2 to calculate right ?

Comment: is the calculation supposed to be `value of current row in column a minus value of previous row in column a`? or just hard coded like in the question?

Comment: @Krishna -  Yes you are right. OP want to calculate in col-a (Row 2 minus Row1), (Row3 minus Row2)...and so on . the result OP want to display in Column - b

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097370/calculation-in-datagridview-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //skip last emtpy line(if don't have, remove -1)
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            int valueCellIndex = 0;//assume calculate the 0th column
            int resultCellIndex = 1;//assume result to put into the 1th column
            //assume values are integers
            var lastRow = dataGridView1.Rows[i - 1];
            var curRow = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
            int last = Convert.ToInt32(lastRow.Cells[valueCellIndex].Value);
            int cur = Convert.ToInt32(curRow.Cells[valueCellIndex].Value);
            curRow.Cells[resultCellIndex].Value = cur - last;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it . but it said " Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'"